# XML DTD Problem

Tags: xml, dtd

Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE email [
    <!ELEMENT email (text)>
    <!ElEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
    ]>
    <email>
    <text>Dear John....;-).</text>
  </email>
```

The document is not well formed.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is wrong is this line:

```
<!ElEMENT text (#PCDATA)>
```

`ElEMENT` needs to be all upper-case.

Answer brought to you courtesy of http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/